# iphone SDK confusion

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I accidentally deleted my sdk 3.0 directory, thinking I didn't need it.
Now when I launch and compile a project it says that my base sdk is missing.

Where can I download the 3.0 sdk? All that is available in Dev Center are the 3.2 and 4 beta sdks?

Comment: All SDKs except 3.2 and 4.0 are fully deprecated for submission. Trying to get around this is fruitless. Check out my community wiki on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.2 SDK includes everything you need to develop for earlier versions too.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this blog post with [direct links to old SDK versions](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/old-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html).

Edit: Direct links that are working, just verified (ADC account required):

- [iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with XCode 3.1.4 for Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.1.4__leopard__9m2809a.dmg)
- [iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with XCode 3.2.1 for Snow Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.1.3__final/iphone_sdk_3.1.3_with_xcode_3.2.1__snow_leopard__10m2003a.dmg)

Thinking about it, you should be able to select an older base SDK.

- Go to Project > Edit Project Settings
- Select "Build" category
- In the section "Architectures", check the setting "Base SDK"

I'm running 3.1.3 and I have every Base SDK down to iPhone Device 2.0.

Comment: no longer available:( I'll try reinstalling the 3.2 Xcode+SDK

Comment: sorry, my bad. Try the new links or check the project settings.

Comment: All SDKs except 3.2 & 4.0 are deprecated for submmission. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Bad luck if you can't/don't want to upgrade to Snow Leopard.